# satadimm reliability as the server operating system

Tags: ssd

I have seen little information about satadimm.  I bought a server for a colocation and it came with a viking 400gig satadimm, the first time for me.  I thought this was pretty cool, and I was told you can load your OS and save your RAID slots for more mirror or whatever.

My best practice is to have my server OS on a mirror in case once crashes,  but from my experience, RAM rarely goes bad.  So how reliable could be running the OS on one of these sticks are really save space on RAID?

or should you buy two satadimms to do mirror from them?  Would have to be software RAID for that I suppose... just thinking out load.

Has anyone played with this or used this in production in this form?  What are your thoughts?

Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

It's not RAM. It's just a SATA drive in DIMM form factor, powered by the RAM slot, attached via a separate cable to the storage controller.

It's convenient when you have spare RAM slots - at least according to the marketing. It behaves like SSD storage, because it's SSD storage.